# send email with smtp in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I send an email via smtp
I receive an AUTH message and it does not allow sending email.
By searching the internet saying that through the command prompt,
I telnet to hostmail, then I realized my type is AUTH NTLM
And I'm not able to authenticate to send my email and I still have time to send the authenticate message.
Most sites have auth plain or auth login for submission and I get a type error message when I use
please guide me
Thank You

after exec query:
declare mailhost VARCHAR2(50) := 'mail:port';
BEGIN
UTL_SMTP.AUTH(mailhost, 'user', 'pass','PLAIN'=> );
UTL_MAIL.SEND(sender => '' , recipients => '' , subject => 'Testmail' , message => 'Hello');
END;

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg748.png

Comment: "... I receive an AUTH message" - that's what you say. Most people prefer exact error message, along with its code (and not your own interpretation of the same).

Comment: What exactly are you using on PL/SQL to send the email?

Comment: @doberkofle yes use plsql

Comment: Sure, but what method, package, library, … are you using?

Comment: package utl_mail

Comment: declare 
  mailhost VARCHAR2(50) := 'mail:port';

BEGIN 
  
    UTL_SMTP.AUTH(mailhost, 'user', 'pass',schemes => );
    UTL_MAIL.SEND(sender     => ''
                , recipients => ''
                , subject    => 'Testmail'
                , message    => 'Hello');

END;

Comment: after telnet 
type ehlo

Comment: 250-SIZE 37748736
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 XRDST

Comment: my error after exec

Comment: wrong number or type of argument in call 'AUTH'

Comment: this is my way @doberkofle

Comment: You should update the question with your code. `UTL_SMTP.AUTH(mailhost, 'user', 'pass',schemes => );` seems to have no value for the parameter `schemes`.

Comment: yes i know 
for sample this code 
when update value and parameter schems 
after recive error

Comment: I really recommend to update your original question with all the needed information and a properly formatted example of your code or else this question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Please, as @doberkofler has pointed out, edit your question adding all the relevant details to help you out.

Comment: edit question@doberkofler-@Ana GH